# Rotate your finger ImageView limited

Tags: android

I have ImageView, which I rotate the finger at both sides. How can I limit the rotation from 0 to 270 degrees?
Sorry for bad English..

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    centerX = VolBt.getWidth() / 2;
    centerY = VolBt.getHeight() / 2;

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {
       savedMatrix.set(matrix);
       startAngle = Math.atan2(event.getY() - centerY, event.getX()  - centerX);
    }

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
    {
        double a = Math.atan2(event.getY() - centerY, event.getX()  - centerX);
        angle = (float) Math.toDegrees(a-startAngle);

        matrix.set(savedMatrix);
        matrix.postRotate(angle, centerX, centerY);
    }

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
    {

    }

    VolBt.setImageMatrix(matrix);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I am pretty sure that you can do this via xml. there are some attributes like  
`android:fromDegrees="0"` and `android:toDegrees="260"` so you can set the value that you want exactly. But I can see your approach is kinda different.

Comment: Unfortunately I can not use xml ...